# Android: Any practices for asyncronous network activities which updates UI

Tags: android, user-interface, networking, android-asynctask, android-handler

I'm developing an application which transmit information to network devices using a TCP connection. My main problem is I need to update UI every time a feedback or alert received from a devices. Since their feedback and response is unpredictable, I can not wait till they respond and user can move between different application `Activities`. So when an alert or feedback receives, I should check which activity is on screen and update UI and pass messages between activities to let them what they should do and this is a complex task for many situation which may happen. 
So I want to ask are there any know practices for this situation? 
e.g. Is it good to run network communications as a service and pass intent to receivers on requires UI updates? Or is it good to run a handler for network communications...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use receivers  as you mentioned, and to detect in which activity the user is watching I would use the onResume and onPause methods in each activity to store the current one on the sqlite database.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). it will allow you to send events like local broadcast receiver. And from that you can listen specific event and display result.